# How do you reflectively call a Go struct's methods?

Tags: go

Say I've got a `ProblemSolver` struct with 1,000+ "problem-solving" methods:

```
type ProblemSolver struct {}

func (ps ProblemSolver) problem1() {
    fmt.Println("Solving problem #1 ...")
    return
}

func (ps ProblemSolver) problem2() {
    fmt.Println("Solving problem #2 ...")
    return
}

...
    
func (ps ProblemSolver) problem1001() {
    fmt.Println("Solving problem #1001 ...")
    return
}
```

And say I want to solve *specific* problems - like problem #1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 19, 20 ... etc.

```
func main() {
    ps := ProblemSolver{}
    problems := [100]int{1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 19, 20 ...}
}
```

I know you could just invoke these "first-class functions" directly, but that has a code smell:

```
ps.problem1()
ps.problem3()
ps.problem4()
...
ps.problem1001()
```

I'm thinking about using `reflect` instead - I tried giving https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection a read, but I found it to be a difficult read.

Is it possible to use `reflect` to invoke only the functions I want (as with the `problems` variable above)?

**EDIT**: I used Burak's solution below to come up with something like this, which works great. Thanks!

```
// Solve : Solves specified problems.
func (ps ProblemSolver) Solve() {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(ps)

    specifiedProblems := []int{1, 3, 4}

    for _, sp := range specifiedProblems{
        methodName := fmt.Sprintf("Problem%d", sp)
        val.MethodByName(methodName).Call(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Volker That function only solves one problem. I want to solve many problems, in a particular order. I should add - this hypothetical `problem()` function would be quite monolithic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call those functions directly:

```
ps.problem1()
ps.problem3()
ps.problem4()
...
```

You can put them in an array and call them:

```
problems:[]func(){ps.problem1,ps.problem3,ps.problem4,...}
for _,x:=range problems {
   x()
}
```

Or you can use reflect:

```
val:=reflect.ValueOf(ps)
val.MethodByName(fmt.Sprintf("Problem%d",num)).Call(nil)
```

The methods are unexported, for reflect to work, you have to export them.

Comment: Thanks Burak - I have updated my question with the solution I went with. I did have to export my methods, by capitalizing the first letter of each function, for this to work. Thank you for your help - now I won't have to write a 20,000 line function that does 100 different things. :)